# How To Share a link similar to Instagram image links on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to find out how to implement this type of link to be shared to my facebook page. I've seen another page do it a while back, they shared a link to their facebook, and it was their own website, and it was this exact same kind of link, here's the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsPaW.png

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Instagram is owned by Facebook now, so their app has some special capabilities that are not available to normal, 3rd-party apps.

Comment: I saw this capability used by another page and site thought, that had around 10,000 likes, like a meme website or something

Comment: Do you have an example?